# consmall signal block diagram

Tags: dc-dc-converter

[image]

According to this figure how do I get equation 4
[image]

Comment: What are \$T_v\$ and \$T_i\$ ? (open) loop gains ? (closed) loop transfer functions ? What is \$T_2\$ ? open loop gain ? closed loop gain ?

Comment: @AJN Sorry I don't mention it 
Tv is Fm*FV*F2
Ti is Fm*Fi*F4

Comment: @AJN  Loop gain T2 is referred ti as the outer loop gain since it is measured outside of the closed current loop.The outer loop gain can be measured using  conventional analog modulation techniques. The outer loop can also be written as a combination of the current and voltage loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The context is not clear to me* but the result can be arrived at by simplifying the block diagram. I have removed unrelated branches as well as some feed forward blocks to show only the two relevant loops; one of which is opened for finding out the open loop transfer function. The loop opening point is the \$\times\$ symbol seen near \$T2\$.

[image: loop block diagram]

The *inner loop* can be simplified as \$\frac{F_m}{1 + F_m F_i F_4} = \frac{F_m}{1+T_i}\$. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-loop_transfer_function)

Then the gain of the cut loop becomes \$\frac{\color{red}{(-1)} F_m F_2 F_v}{1+T_i} = \frac{\color{red}{(-1)}  T_v}{1+T_i}\$. When writing the open loop gain of negative feedback systems the negative sign shown above is *implied* and not actually written down.

When analyzing the stability of the given loops, the feed forward terms such as `F1`, `F2`, `F5` etc. are not relevant.

Comment: I think I know, Thanks. 
And I have more question can I ask you?

Comment: If it is closely related to this answer, do ask. If not, it may be better to open a new question.

Comment: I open a new question,but it is related to this
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535381/small-signal-digram