# Small signal digram

Tags: control-system, signal-processing, transient

[image]

[image]

According to this figure how to get qeuation(7)and(8)

Comment: Write down the expression on each line of the diagram. The lines which have two different expressions obtained by different paths give equations.

Comment: \$T_v, i_L\$ are not shown or given, nor the book reference

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I try it but still have no answer can you give more tips?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Tv=Gcv*FM*Gvd
Ti=Gci*Fm*Gid
This is IEEE paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1353336

Comment: Try re-drawing the diagram as in the [linked question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535090/consmall-signal-block-diagram?noredirect=1&lq=1) so that the diagram looks like a simple loop with no signal lines crossing over each other. Try (7) first; it seems much easier to redraw.

Comment: @AJN OK I will try it

Comment: @AJN I'v solved the (7), but (8) is difficult for me , I don't know how to simplify the (b), I use the same way but can't not get the answer

Comment: 2004 Article using  the false assumptions in Intel's Roadmap using Moore's Law... According to Intel’s
roadmap, by the year 2010, over one billion transistors will be
integrated in one processor; the processor’s clock speed will
approach 15 GHz; the core static currents will increase up to
200 A;  (Not true even in 2020 but maybe 5.2GHz 8 core or a Xeon with 48 cores) Its all about lower power per MIP now competing with TMSC.

Comment: (8) Doesn't seem to have any simple loops which can be simplified. You might try the method suggested by @EugeneSh.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  you mean this article is wrong?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks your link

Comment: @AJN I still can't derive it. it takes all day, I am really confused.

Comment: It's a fairly old article and not well documented showing real schematic associated with gain blocks and real example.  Look for citations and followup on newer articles, dont sweat. I didn't get it either,  Or better write to the author or ask a Prof.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 OK, thanks for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it seems you have already worked out the transfer function for `3.a` \$G_{ii-cv}\$. To get the transfer function for `3.b`, we can use the utilize the previous result. Below, I have shown the diagram `3.b` with three simplifications :

1. \$G_{cv}\$ shifted up-stream of the summing point (split into two pieces).
2. \$F_m\$ shifted down-stream of the junction (split into two pieces).
3. Consecutive blocks are merged.

The additional connection in `3.b` compared to `3.a` is shown in green and the part in black color is same as diagram `3.a`.

[image: partially simplified block diagram]

The transfer function if the green signal was **not** present is

$$
i_L = \frac{G_{ii}(1+T_v) + G_{id}\ G_{cv}\ F_m\ Z{o}}{1+T_v} i_o
$$

Applying block diagram reduction any further, looked difficult. So I followed the advice from the first comment to the question. The effect of green signal on the transfer function is written out explicitly.

$$
i_L = \frac{G_{ii}(1+T_v) + G_{id}\ G_{cv}\ F_m\ Z{o}}{1+T_v} i_o - i_L \frac{1}{1+T_v} G_{id}\ F_m\ G_{ci}
$$

Simplifying we get,

$$
i_L \left( 1 + T_v + T_i \right) = G_{ii}(1+T_v) + G_{id}\ G_{cv}\ F_m\ Z{o}\ i_o
$$

Note : I have not closely looked at the signs at the summing junctions. Use the above  as a guide and re-derive the expression yourself.

Comment: Thanks your help

Answer (score 0):

I must confess, I can't explain it in 25 words or less, so I won't try. This just adds some details missing in your question.

There are a lot of assumptions made and things left out in the article.

Most important, is NEVER USE IDEAL VOLTAGE SOURCES FOR ANY SIMULATION, Because EVERYTHING HAS SOME SPECTRAL IMPEDANCE. If the output cap was perfect, you'd never get any load step voltage errors and the design becomes unstable.

I think idea is to use positive current feed forward or feedback with a gain <1 so that it is stable responds faster to transient step load faster than any inductor. Every CMOS transistor is essential a transient RdsOn Coss, RC ministep.  When you get millions switching synchronously in a CPU, that's a big transient load.

Ideally in any closed loop system you want 1st order feedback for every parameter but integrating inductors cause 2nd order  effects, so differentiating RC compensation feedback helps by reducing the order of the T slope towards stable proportional 1st order loops, but RC compensation only helps in the upper spectrum without knowing the % DC max current.

So I am just adding some diagrams for all users to understand the article better and a [link that does NOT have an IEEE paywall and allows free registration.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/FCY_Lee/publication/3280631_Critical_Bandwidth_for_the_Load_Transient_Response_of_Voltage_Regulator_Modules/links/589883d24585158bf6f6b902/Critical-Bandwidth-for-the-Load-Transient-Response-of-Voltage-Regulator-Modules.pdf)

\$Z_o=\dfrac{v_o}{i_o}\$ (open loop driver impedance)
\$T_v= G_{cv}F_mG_{vd}\$ ( transfer function from \$v_o\$ to differential + input compare added to \$-i_oZ_o\$)  while Fm represents some comparator effect (hysteresis? or just polarity)

- (TL;DR) I assume that uses some R ratio feedback of output v down to reference voltage, and attenuation from PWM duty cycle of output voltage which affects closed/open loop output impedance.

The attenuated voltage feedback for inverted voltage feedback, Tv uses the gain of a non-inverting Op AMP is 1+inverting gain

[image]